Curl command to create a bug in Azure DevOps
Getting below error while creating a bug in Azure DevOps using the below API in cmd, tried using PAT with Read Write & Manage permission
curl "https://dev.azure.com/online/NewRelic/_apis/wit/workitems/$bug?api-version=7.1-preview.3" -H "Authorization: Bearer cacc" -H "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json" --data-binary '[{"op":"add","path":"/fields/System.Title","value":"Test bug by salman"}]'

Error:-
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://**">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>


If you are using a Bourne-compatible shell and the string $bug is supposed to be literal, you need to backslash the $, or use single quotes instead of double.

Does this answer your question? What are the differences between single and double quotes in Bash?

curl 'https://dev.azure.com///_apis/wit/workitems/$bug?api-version=7.1-preview.3' -H 'Authorization: Bearer **' -H 'Content-Type: application/json-patch+json' --data-binary '[{"op":"add","path":"/fields/System.Title","value":"Test bug by salman"}]'
curl: (3) URL rejected: Port number was not a decimal number between 0 and 65535
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Bearer
curl: (3) URL rejected: Bad hostname
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

You have blotted out the parts which could produce the error, so all we can tell you is what's already in the error message.

those are just the name of org, name of project and in authorization after Bearer its PAT

They are not; you can only get this error message if you have something invalid after dev.azure.com. Maybe you forgot a slash after dev.azure.com?

You haven't revealed which shell you are using. If it's not a Unix shell, the quoting rules are probably different. The "Bearer" error you got vaguely suggests that you might be using cmd ...?

tried in cmd with same error, curl 'https://dev.azure.com/online/NewRelic/_apis/wit/workitems/$bug?api-version=7.1-preview.3' -H 'Authorization: Bearer hsv' -H 'Content-Type: application/json-patch+json' --data-binary '[{"op":"add","path":"/fields/System.Title","value":"Test bug by salman"}]'

cmd doesn't support single quotes at all. Does your comment mean that you were actually using Bash before?

i am trying in cmd

Based on your requirement, you are using cmd to run the curl command to create the bug work item.
To meet your requirement, you can use the following curl command:
curl -u :PAT  "https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_apis/wit/workitems/$BUG?api-version=7.0"  -H "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json" --data-binary "[{\"op\":\"add\",\"path\":\"/fields/System.Title\",\"value\":\"Test bug by salman\"}]"

Or
curl -u :PAT  "https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_apis/wit/workitems/$BUG?api-version=7.0"  -H "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json" --data-binary "[{'op':'add','path':'/fields/System.Title','value':'Test bug by salman'}]"

Then you can use the Rest API to create the Bug work item in Azure DevOps.

{"$id":"1","customProperties":{"FieldReferenceName":null,"FieldStatusFlags":"none","ErrorMessage":"TF401320: Rule Error for field Type. Error code: Required, HasValues, LimitedToValues, AllowsOldValue, InvalidEmpty. 4 additional errors occurred during validation of the work item. Please correct all errors and try again.","FieldStatusCode":0,"RuleValidationErrors":[{"fieldReferenceName":"Custom.Type","fieldStatusFlags":"required, hasValues, limitedToValues, allowsOldValue, invalidEmpty","errorMessage":"TF401320: Rule Error for field Type. Error code: Required, HasValues, LimitedToValues,

this is the error i am getting, missing lines in error due to lengthy error

@Salman From the error message, it seems that the work item has a field name: type. Can you confirm it? If yes, the error means that you need to input the value to the type filed due to work item rule when you create the work item.

yes worked, had to add some more fields which are mandatory it seems

Glad to know that it can work for you.
